# Negative margin on table row

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I give a `<tr>` a negative margin to move it up? I'm trying to move `.small-item-block`

```
<tr>
  <td class="item-name">Caprese</td>
  <td class="item-description">Fresh mozzarella, tomato, fresh basil and balsamic vinegar on a bed of spinach.</td>
  <td>$4.00</td>
  <td>$20.00</td>
</tr>
<tr class="small-item-block" >
  <td class="item-name"></td>
  <td class="item-addition-name">Add Bacon</td>
  <td class="item-addition-price">$1.00</td>
  <td class="item-addition-price">$3.00</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
tr.small-item-block  {
   margin-top: -10px;
   border-spacing: -10px;
}
```

Here is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4gLM/1).

Comment: moving up? Can you please give more information about your intention? Generally it is not recommended to give negative values to margins. I also think that margin is for escaping from the adjacents not for making things to closer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really move a row any higher than the row above it, so I think your best bet would be to remove margin/padding from the `<td>`s inside that `<tr>`. Example:

```
tr.small-item-block td {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I used this method, lessened the padding on `td` then gave each `.item-block` more padding, and each `.small-item-block` no padding.

Answer (score 15):

You can't move a tr, but you can set the `td`'s to `position: relative`, and then set a negative `top` property, like:

```
tr.small-item-block td {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Here's your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/L4gLM/2/